# How to make a table/figure not to be placed in middle of a paragraph in a new page?

Tags: tables, floats, captions, positioning

Is there a way to make table/figure not located in the middle of a paragraph in the new pages?

I had tried:

```
\begin{table}[htp!]
```

and

```
\begin{table}[h!]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

 \usepackage{showframe}
 \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
 \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{makecell,siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 

Testtesttestest
Testtesttestest
Testtesttestest
Testtesttestest
Testtesttestest Testtesttes
Testtesttestest Testtesttes

To save some time when writing too many expressions 
with exponents is by defining a new command to make simpler:
To save some time when writing too many expressions 
with exponents is by defining a new command to make simpler:
To save some time when writing too many expressions 
with exponents is by defining a new command to make simpler:
To save some time when writing too many expressions 
with exponents is by defining a new command to make simpler:
To save some time when writing too many expressions 
with exponents is by defining a new command to make simpler:

To save some time when writing too many expressions 
with exponents is by defining a new command to make simpler:
To save some time when writing too many expressions 
with exponents is by defining a new command to make simpler:
To save some time when writing too many expressions 
with exponents is by defining a new command to make simpler:
To save some time when writing too many expressions 
with exponents is by defining a new command to make simpler:
To save some time when writing too many expressions 
with exponents is by defining a new command to make simpler:
"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe."

"The day I picked my dog up from the pound was one of the happiest days of both of our lives. I had gone to the pound just a week earlier with the idea that I would just "look" at a puppy. Of course, you can no more just look at those squiggling little faces so filled with hope and joy than you can stop the sun from setting in the evening. I knew within minutes of walking in the door that I would get a puppy… but it wasn't until I saw him that I knew I had found my puppy."

"Looking for houses was supposed to be a fun and exciting process. Unfortunately, none of the ones that we saw seemed to match the specifications that we had established. They were too small, too impersonal, too close to the neighbors. After days of finding nothing even close, we began to wonder: was there really a perfect house out there for us?"

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

"Billy Ray's Pawn Shop and Lawn Mower Repair looked like a burial ground for country auction rejects. The blazing, red, diesel fuel tanks beamed in front of the station, looking like cheap lipstick against the pallid, wrinkled texture of the parking lot sand. The yard, not much larger than the end zone at General G. Patton High School on the north end of town, was framed with a rusted metallic hedge of lawn mowers, banana seat bicycles, and corroded oil drums. It wasn't a calico frame of rusted parts, but rather an orchestra of unwanted machinery that Billy Ray had arranged into sections. The yellow-tanked mowers rested silently at the right of the diesel fuel. Once red, now faded orange, mowers stood at attention to the left. The oil barrels, jaded and pierced with holes, bellared like chimes when the wind was right. The bikes rested sporadically throughout the lot. In the middle of it all was the office, a faded, steel roof supported by cheap two-by-fours and zebra paneling. Billy Ray was at home, usually, five blocks east of town on Kennel Road."

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want the table to float simply do not use environment `table`. Use instead this code:

```
%\begin{table}[htp!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
%\end{table}
```

Please see I commented environment `table` and command `\centering` and used environment `center` instead.

If it could be that the position of your table/figure is very near at the end of the page it could happen with the code before that caption and table are placed on two different pages :-(

To omit that use the following code (`minipage` keeps table and caption together, with using environment `minipage` you can use again `\centering` instead environment `center`):

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth} % <=====================================
\centering
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{the wantet title of table a} % <======================
\label{tab:titlea} % <==================================================
\end{minipage} % <======================================================
```

With the following complete MWE (please see I deleted the closing `\\` of your paragraphs. Do not do that, use a blank line to mark a new paragraph!):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

 \usepackage{showframe}
 \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
 \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{makecell,siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 

"When entering the door at Lou's, two things are immediately noticeable: the place is rarely empty and seems to consist of a maze of rooms. The first room, through the door, is the main part of the restaurant. There is another, rarely used, dining room off to the right. It was added during the oil well boom of the seventies. Through the main dining room is yet another room; it guards the door leading into the kitchen. This room contains the most coveted table in the place. The highest tribute Lou can bestow on anyone is to allow them access to seats at this table. This table is the family table; it is reserved for Lou's, and her daughter Karen's, immediate family and treasured friends."

"Like his twisted feathers, his many scars, the reliable old owl chose the gnarled, weather-beaten, but solid branch often - it being a companion to the wise alone with the night and the last branch to creak in the heaviest wind. He often came to survey the fields and the clouds before his hunt, to listen to the steady sound of the stream passing through reeds under the bridge, while combing his feathers for the unwanteds - whatever they might be."

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe."

"The day I picked my dog up from the pound was one of the happiest days of both of our lives. I had gone to the pound just a week earlier with the idea that I would just "look" at a puppy. Of course, you can no more just look at those squiggling little faces so filled with hope and joy than you can stop the sun from setting in the evening. I knew within minutes of walking in the door that I would get a puppy… but it wasn't until I saw him that I knew I had found my puppy."

"Looking for houses was supposed to be a fun and exciting process. Unfortunately, none of the ones that we saw seemed to match the specifications that we had established. They were too small, too impersonal, too close to the neighbors. After days of finding nothing even close, we began to wonder: was there really a perfect house out there for us?"

Below is a pdf link to personal statements and application essays representing strong efforts by students applying for both undergraduate and graduate opportunities. These ten essays have one thing in common: They were all written by students under the constraint of the essay being 1-2 pages due to the target program’s explicit instructions. In such circumstances, writers must attend carefully to the essay prompt (sometimes as simple as “Write a one-page summary of your reasons for wanting to pursue graduate study”) and recognize that evaluators tend to judge these essays on the same fundamental principles, as follows:

%\begin{table}[htp!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
%\end{table}

"Billy Ray's Pawn Shop and Lawn Mower Repair looked like a burial ground for country auction rejects. The blazing, red, diesel fuel tanks beamed in front of the station, looking like cheap lipstick against the pallid, wrinkled texture of the parking lot sand. The yard, not much larger than the end zone at General G. Patton High School on the north end of town, was framed with a rusted metallic hedge of lawn mowers, banana seat bicycles, and corroded oil drums. It wasn't a calico frame of rusted parts, but rather an orchestra of unwanted machinery that Billy Ray had arranged into sections. The yellow-tanked mowers rested silently at the right of the diesel fuel. Once red, now faded orange, mowers stood at attention to the left. The oil barrels, jaded and pierced with holes, bellared like chimes when the wind was right. The bikes rested sporadically throughout the lot. In the middle of it all was the office, a faded, steel roof supported by cheap two-by-fours and zebra paneling. Billy Ray was at home, usually, five blocks east of town on Kennel Road."

"When entering the door at Lou's, two things are immediately noticeable: the place is rarely empty and seems to consist of a maze of rooms. The first room, through the door, is the main part of the restaurant. There is another, rarely used, dining room off to the right. It was added during the oil well boom of the seventies. Through the main dining room is yet another room; it guards the door leading into the kitchen. This room contains the most coveted table in the place. The highest tribute Lou can bestow on anyone is to allow them access to seats at this table. This table is the family table; it is reserved for Lou's, and her daughter Karen's, immediate family and treasured friends.

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

If you want a blank line in your printed document use package `parskip` (see documentation of it with `texdoc parskip`) ...

## EDIT:

To get an caption for the table or figure please see the following MWE (code changings marked with `<====`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

 \usepackage{showframe}
 \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
 \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{makecell,siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{parskip} % <================================================
\usepackage{caption} % <================================================


\begin{document} 

"When entering the door at Lou's, two things are immediately noticeable: the place is rarely empty and seems to consist of a maze of rooms. The first room, through the door, is the main part of the restaurant. There is another, rarely used, dining room off to the right. It was added during the oil well boom of the seventies. Through the main dining room is yet another room; it guards the door leading into the kitchen. This room contains the most coveted table in the place. The highest tribute Lou can bestow on anyone is to allow them access to seats at this table. This table is the family table; it is reserved for Lou's, and her daughter Karen's, immediate family and treasured friends."

"Like his twisted feathers, his many scars, the reliable old owl chose the gnarled, weather-beaten, but solid branch often - it being a companion to the wise alone with the night and the last branch to creak in the heaviest wind. He often came to survey the fields and the clouds before his hunt, to listen to the steady sound of the stream passing through reeds under the bridge, while combing his feathers for the unwanteds - whatever they might be."

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe."

"The day I picked my dog up from the pound was one of the happiest days of both of our lives. I had gone to the pound just a week earlier with the idea that I would just "look" at a puppy. Of course, you can no more just look at those squiggling little faces so filled with hope and joy than you can stop the sun from setting in the evening. I knew within minutes of walking in the door that I would get a puppy… but it wasn't until I saw him that I knew I had found my puppy."

"Looking for houses was supposed to be a fun and exciting process. Unfortunately, none of the ones that we saw seemed to match the specifications that we had established. They were too small, too impersonal, too close to the neighbors. After days of finding nothing even close, we began to wonder: was there really a perfect house out there for us?"

Below is a pdf link to personal statements and application essays representing strong efforts by students applying for both undergraduate and graduate opportunities. These ten essays have one thing in common: They were all written by students under the constraint of the essay being 1-2 pages due to the target program’s explicit instructions. In such circumstances, writers must attend carefully to the essay prompt (sometimes as simple as “Write a one-page summary of your reasons for wanting to pursue graduate study”) and recognize that evaluators tend to judge these essays on the same fundamental principles, as follows:

%\begin{table}[htp!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{the wantet title of table} % <========================
\label{tab:title} % <===================================================
\end{center}
%\end{table}

"Billy Ray's Pawn Shop and Lawn Mower Repair looked like a burial ground 
for country auction rejects. The blazing, red, diesel fuel tanks beamed 
in front of the station, looking like cheap lipstick against the pallid, 
wrinkled texture of the parking lot sand. The yard, not much larger than 
the end zone at General G. Patton High School on the north end of town, 
was framed with a rusted metallic hedge of lawn mowers, banana seat 
bicycles, and corroded oil drums. It wasn't a calico frame of rusted 
parts, but rather an orchestra of unwanted machinery that Billy Ray had 
arranged into sections. The yellow-tanked mowers rested silently at the 
%right of the diesel fuel. Once red, now faded orange, mowers stood at 
%attention to the left. The oil barrels, jaded and pierced with holes, 
%bellared like chimes when the wind was right. The bikes rested 
%sporadically throughout the lot. In the middle of it all was the office, 
%a faded, steel roof supported by cheap two-by-fours and zebra paneling. 
Billy Ray was at home, usually, five blocks east of town on Kennel Road."

\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth} % <=====================================
\centering
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{the wantet title of table a} % <======================
\label{tab:titlea} % <==================================================
\end{minipage} % <======================================================

"When entering the door at Lou's, two things are immediately noticeable: the place is rarely empty and seems to consist of a maze of rooms. The first room, through the door, is the main part of the restaurant. There is another, rarely used, dining room off to the right. It was added during the oil well boom of the seventies. Through the main dining room is yet another room; it guards the door leading into the kitchen. This room contains the most coveted table in the place. The highest tribute Lou can bestow on anyone is to allow them access to seats at this table. This table is the family table; it is reserved for Lou's, and her daughter Karen's, immediate family and treasured friends.

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: result mwe two]

Please see (marked red arrow 1) the first code for the table with caption, and amrked wirh red arrow 2 the solution with `minipage`. Please see that I commented some lines of your text before table 2 (red arrow 3) to get it at the end of the page. Now copy the MWE and begin to delete one ore more comments, compile and see the changed result ...

Comment: thanks. How about figure, table if I am writing a thesis that need `table of content` and `List of Figure` and `List of Table`. I need use `\begin{figure}`

Comment: and also, i need to add `\caption` and `\label`

Comment: Then you can use `\captionof{figure}{the wantet title of figure}\label{fig:title}` from package `caption` and change `{figure}` to `{table}` for your tables. See documentation: `texdoc caption` ...

Comment: do you mean i added in the last part as `\end{center}
\captionof{figure}{the wanted title of figure}
\label{tab:the wanted title of figure}`?. It seemed not showing `Fig.1. Blablabla`

Comment: Please see updated answer ...

Comment: thanks! it worked. Any idea about adding in `figure`. I tried `\begin{center}
    \includegraphics{name/PilotStudy.png}
\captionof{figure}{fdsfdsf}=====================
\label{tab:fdsfdsf} 
\end{center}` without putting `\begin{figure}`, the figure does not shown up

Comment: If you have problems with figures please **ask a new question.** We do not like "living questions" here constantly changed in comments. And add to the new question, if you have error messages in the log file. If yes, add the **first** error message **to your question** (please see, the linepages are important, so do not show them in comment!)

Comment: @Mensch: You might want to surround the `center` environment with a minipage. With your current setup you "risk"  a pagebreak between tabular and captionof.

Comment: @Mensch, I will ask in a new question and link to this

Comment: @Mensch, is there any disadvantages using `\captionof{figure}{the wantet title of figure}\label{fig:title}` beside it does not split between the paragraph in new page

Comment: @leandriis, can you explain more on this `You might want to surround the center environment with a minipage. With your current setup you "risk" a pagebreak between tabular and captionof.`

Comment: @aan: Add some more text before the image untill the space at the bottom of the page is too small for the image+caption. Without a `minipage` that contains both image and caption, you can gt a pagebreak between image and caption leaving image at the bottom of the first page and the caption at the top of the following page. With a `minipage` surrounding the `center` environment you can prevent this pagebreak and the image+caption will be shifted to the top of the following page.

Comment: @leandriis I added a second example for the table, thanks.

Comment: @aan Each code can have disadvantages, but looking at your given code my solution (also the edited) will work with no disadvantages. Of course things change if you change the given code, for example move the table more at the end of the page or load other packages like `hyperref`, which can result in another solvable issue with `\captionof` and `caption`. **Therefore it is very important you make a good question, containing all relevant used code for the issue.** That is the art of making a MWE, not really easy IMHO, but you will get better with every new MWE you created ...